# Do site statistics still matter after graduation?- Revamp

Tags: discussion, support

I <strike>was</strike> am still wondering whether the much-pursued site statistics are still relevant now we are graduated?

For example, I have been answering quite a few oldies just now (<strike>2013, 2014</strike> 29 [revival](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) badges), but does that still benefit our site (% answered questions in this case), or should we rather focus on new (likely more rep-yielding and more visible) questions?

Also, is cleaning up of dusty low-quality answers still paramount (<strike>also for the %answered</strike> as it was in beta)? With a chat with @Chris I think it is indeed good to keep the quality up, but how *necessary*/crucial is it now?

Comment: At least it is not displayed anymore on the start page.

Comment: @Chris - No, exactly. Also the Area 51 link is gone.

Comment: Area 51 is not responsible for graduated sites.

Comment: @Chris - do you ever sleep ;)

Comment: Do I have to? It's 2pm for me right now :-)

Comment: @Chris :) I didn't mean you have to sleep now *per se*, but it just seemed to me you were on SE for days straight :) It may be me..... I want my privileges back haha

Comment: As long as they are *significant* !! :D (Stat joke)